# Translating an optional json field into an option using Play Json?

Tags: scala, playframework

I would like to do something like this:

```
(request.body \ "optional-integer").toOption[Int]
```

Such that if there is no `optional-integer` field in the body, I will get a `None`, and otherwise the integer value.
Is there any idiomatic way?

Comment: can you please explain with the use case? I can't get you. :)

Comment: In place of `toOption[Int]`, just put `asOpt[Int]`.

Answer (score 0):

As [@Mikesname's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38853404/translating-an-optional-json-field-into-an-option-using-play-json#comment65549302_38853404) said,

```
(request.body \ "optional-integer").asOpt[Int]
```

should do the job. This uses [`JsValue`](https://playframework.com/documentation/2.0/api/scala/play/api/libs/json/JsValue.html).`asOpt()`, which

> Tries to convert the node into a T.

Compare [the *JSON basics* manual, part *Using JsValue.as/asOpt*](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaJson#Using-JsValue.as/asOpt)

> ```
> val nameOption = (json \ "name").asOpt[String]
> // Some("Watership Down")
>
> val bogusOption = (json \ "bogus").asOpt[String]
> // None
> ```